# $unwind Addresses from Person collection with MongoDB using Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, jongo

Hi I am having problems using Jongo to get a list of Addresses from my collection of Persons using the `$unwind` operator.

As you can see I defined the Person class as follows:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long personId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Address> addresses;
//getters and setters
```

and the Address class is defined like:

```
public class Address {
    private String houseNumber;
    private String road;
    private String town;
    private String postalCode;
//gettes and setters
```

The Query is pretty simple:

```
public List<Address> getAddressByPersonId(long id) {
    List<Address> list = persons.aggregate("{$project:{addresses:1}}")
                                    .and("{$match:{_id:#}}",id)
                                    .and("{$unwind: '$addresses'}")
                                    .as(Address.class);
    return list;
}
```

My collection:

```
> db.persons.find()
{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 34, "addresses" : [   {       "houseNumber" : "12",
"road" : "High Street",         "town" : "Small Town",  "postalCode" : "BC2 3DE"
 },     {       "houseNumber" : "12",   "road" : "High Street",         "town" :
 "Small Town",  "postalCode" : "BC2 3DE" } ], "_id" : NumberLong(1) }
>
```

I have a JUnit test for this as well:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        service = new PersonServiceImpl();

        //store a person into the database (manually) before the tests
        MongoCollection persons = Database.getInstance().getCollection(CollectionNames.PERSONS);
        //create a new person
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setPersonId(1L);
        p.setName("Bob");
        p.setAge(34);
        //create two addresses for this person
        Address a = new Address();


        a.setHouseNumber("33");
        a.setRoad("Fake Road");
        a.setPostalCode("AB1 2CD");
        a.setTown("Big Town");
        p.addAddress(a);

        a.setHouseNumber("12");
        a.setRoad("High Street");
        a.setPostalCode("BC2 3DE");
        a.setTown("Small Town");
        p.addAddress(a);

        persons.save(p);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        service = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void getAddressesByPersonIdTest(){

        List<Address> list = service.getAddressByPersonId(1L);
        for (Address item : list){
            item.print();
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(list.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
### Address: null null, null, null 
### Address: null null, null, null
```

I don't understand very well what the problem is. Apparently the test **does not fail** (so `list.size()` is bigger than zero...but prints null). The `print()` method is tested and works.

I would like to get the two Bob's addresses , however the query returns null objects. Am I missing something? Should I use the **$unwind** differently? Please suggest

Comment: you are trying to convert bob objects into address objects - addresses are embedded in top level object.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation Framework returns the exact same format as goes into it - after the unwind the only difference is how many addresses are embedded under the `addresses` field.  In your case you get back two documents which are:

```
{ "_id": 1,
  "name" : "Bob", 
  "age" : 34, 
  "addresses" : { "houseNumber" : "12", 
                  "road" : "High Street",
                  "town" : "Small Town",
                  "postalCode" : "BC2 3DE"
  }
}
```

This is not converting to Address class very effectively because as you can see, Address object is the value of `addresses` field, and not the top level object.

What is not clear is why you need to aggregate at all - you are getting a list of addresses for a person.  When you do a simple `find()` on the person by Id, the field "addresses" is already a `List` of `Address` objects.

In MongoDB [find() has the option to return just selected fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find), or exclude named fields (analogous to SQL's SELECT * not being as efficient as SELECT col1,col2) so if you do [the Java equivalent of](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29)  `db.persons.find({filter-condition}, {"_id":0, "addresses":1})` you will get back a document with *only* a list of addresses.

Comment: Yes I understand that, my point is that if I have a Person with a field 'addresses' a field 'purchases-history' a field 'search-history' a field 'credit-cards' (just as an example)... Why would I need to map the entire top level object when I only need the addresses?
Pheraps my approach is completly wrong, but @Shad's answer solve my question. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of it, but you do not have to receive the entire document when you query MongoDB.  find() takes two arguments, the first is a "filter" - like a where clause, the second is a list of fields either to include or to exclude.  All you need is to specify that you want back _{ "_id":0, "addresses":1}_ and you get back _just_ a list of addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add some extra information to solve the problem using Jongo.

I wanted to map Mongo results straight to a list of `Addresses` object, avoiding unnecessary instantiation of `Person` objects. Imagine my `Person` class has these extra fields:

```
...
List<Address> addresses; 
List<Purchases> purchases; 
List<Payments> creditcards;
List<Product> watchlist;
//etc
...
```

However we only need to retrieve `'addresses'`. So the first approach could be:

**Solution 1)**

```
public List<Address> getAddressByPersonId(long id) {
        List<Address> list = persons.aggregate("{$match: {_id: #}}", id)
                .and("{$project: {addresses: 1, _id: 0}}")
                .and("{$unwind: '$addresses'}")
                .and("{$project: {houseNumber:'$addresses.houseNumber', road:'$addresses.road', town:'$addresses.town', postalCode:'$addresses.postalCode'}}")
                .as(Address.class);
        return list;
    }
```

**Pros:** I only need a list of `Addresses`, less memory allocation. **Cons:** I need to `$project` every field of the `Address` class otherwise this will not be mapped in Jongo (null). As `@Asya Kamsky` pointed out, this is not scalable solution.

**Solution 2)**

```
public List<Address> getAddressByPersonId(long id) {
        List<Person> list = persons.aggregate("{$match:{_id:#}}",id).and("{$project: {addresses: 1, _id: 0}}")
                .as(Person.class);

        return list.get(0).getAddresses();
    }
```

**Pros:** I don't need to specify which fields of the `adddress` list we want. So it is a scalable solution in the case I want to add an extra field. **Cons:** I need to allocate the whole `Person` object which can translate into considerable overhead when dealing with complex objects and loads of records in similar scenarios.

If you have any other working (Jongo) solutions please share it.